# Как работают конструкции языка в памяти\на ассемблере?

Tags: c++

Подскажите с поиском, ни как не могу сформулировать вопрос чтобы его в сети найти. Я хочу найти инфу о том как работают конструкции языка в памяти и как это происходит на ассемблере, а то мне не достаточно описания этих абстракций: типо конструктор это то-то, метод это то-то, и в целом они для этого...

Может есть где ресурс говорящий об этой работе, или программы?

Comment: Смотрите генерируемый компилятором ассемблерный листинг исходного кода.

Comment: https://beginners.re/

Comment: [Петцольд Ч. "Код"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi_qbjg9LDhAhUFtosKHWKwAGAQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2F1553.ru%2Flessons%2Fuploaded%2FCODE_-_Charlz_Pettsold.pdf&usg=AOvVaw17baTPSdtdWwQhMKo8NIpK)

Comment: Огромная благодарность за beginners.re! Все что надо, там есть. Спасибо.